# « I am full of questions! » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

J'ai une question sur cette traduction :

> Je suis plein de questions !

Est-ce que la phrase susmentionnée (j'adore ce mot) fonctionne ?
Il s'agit de la phrase en anglais : « I am full of questions! ».

Comment: `Susmentionnée` est un terme employé quasi exclusivement dans des textes juridiques, je dirais plutôt « la phrase ci-dessus » ou » la phrase précédente ».

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Non !

Plutôt : "j'ai plein de questions" ou "j'ai un tas de questions"

Comment: (+1) Réponse concise mais très juste. Variante possible de ta deuxième phrase : *J'ai **un** tas de questions.*

Comment: Je connais une variante avec [_paquet_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/paquet) au lieu de _tas_; autrement p-ê plus faible mais simplement « j'ai bien des questions ».

Comment: @RomainVALERI: j'ai eu comme un doute en voyant votre commentaire, tant que j'ai changé ma réponse, mais en y repensant «un tas» et «des tas» fonctionnent tous les deux

Comment: *J'ai beaucoup de questions* me semble aussi une formule acceptable, et plus simple... *j'ai de nombreuses questions* également (quoi que plus formel)

Comment: @Bartdude oui, simplement l'original en anglais est vraiment très casual. Dans tous les cas, le sens est identique